# Magento 2 : How to create Store Configuration multiselect with Payment methods

Tags: magento2, admin, configuration

I want to create a multiselect in the admin area which lists out payment methods.

Has anyone got any experience of this?

Just need system.xml and source model if applicable.  I can sort rest.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

**system.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="getsquare" sortOrder="999" translate="label">
        <label>GetSquare</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="sales" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
        <label>Sales</label>
        <tab>GetSquare</tab>
         
  <resource>NameSpace_ModuleName::config_getsquare_adminpayments</resource>
        <group id="getsquare" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label">
            <label>NameSpace</label>
            <field id="adminpayments" showInDefault="1" showInStore="1" showInWebsite="1" sortOrder="10" translate="label" type="multiselect">
                <label>Admin Payments</label>
                <source_model>NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Adminpayments</source_model>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
</config>
```

then add **Source.php**

```
<?php
namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use \Magento\Payment\Model\Config;

class Adminpayments extends \Magento\Framework\DataObject 
 implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{
  protected $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
  protected $_paymentModelConfig;
  public function __construct(
    ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface,
    Config $paymentModelConfig
  ) {
      $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
      $this->_paymentModelConfig = $paymentModelConfig;
 }
 public function toOptionArray()
 {
      $payments = $this->_paymentModelConfig->getActiveMethods();
      $methods = array();
      foreach ($payments as $paymentCode => $paymentModel) {
          $paymentTitle = $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface
            ->getValue('payment/'.$paymentCode.'/title');
          $methods[$paymentCode] = array(
            'label' => $paymentTitle,
            'value' => $paymentCode
        );
      }
      return $methods;
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep works - thanks

Comment: how to get also  non active payment method in  multi select field

Comment: try this getPaymentMethods() instead of getActiveMethods() @divyasekar

Comment: no, its not working it reflects a https://prnt.sc/pvuofc

Comment: getActiveMethods()  reflects https://prnt.sc/pvup7d and getPaymentMethods() reflects a https://prnt.sc/pvuofc

Comment: https://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-payment-methods-all-active-used/

Comment: I would suggest using the Source from Magento_Payment
`<source_model>Magento\Payment\Model\Config\Source\Allmethods</source_model>`